# Java TreeSet remove duplicates based on object attribute

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I wish to use `TreeSet` to remove duplicate object based on their attributes (here is `toString()` which return object's name ), here is my code :

```
Set<Object> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Object>() {          
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                if (o1.toString().equals(o2.toString())) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });
s.addAll(listComCopy);
listComCopy.clear();
listComCopy.addAll(s);
```

`listComCopy` is a list of object.

It does the work but it only compares consecutive objects on the list, so if i have `list(50).equals(list(150))` it will ignore.

Do you have any idea of how can i refactor this code to eliminate all duplicates regardeless their order in the list?

Comment: In Java 8, you can use `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compare` method does not adhere to the requirements.

See [Comparator.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) ...

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a **negative integer**, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is **less than**, equal to, or greater than the second.

You would be better off using [String.compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) in your `compare`.

```
    Set<Object> s = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

According to TreeSet's constructor [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> TreeSet(Comparator comparator)
>   Constructs a new, empty tree set, **sorted according to the specified comparator**.

The comparator you are providing is only used for sorting, not for duplicate removal.

If you want to remove duplicates, you should implement `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` on your object class you are storing on this TreeSet, so duplicate removal logic will work out of the box when you add a new element to it.

Comment: Maybe you should re-read the linked documentation, especially the part saying “*a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method*”

Comment: +1 Interesting, the constructor javadoc was misleading and some might argue TreeSet kinda breaks Set contract by not using equals and hashcode. Shame on you, java.

Comment: Well, the documentation says *exactly* that, the `TreeSet` fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface in cases where the order is not consistent with `equals`. The hash code is irrelevant as it is not part of the general `Set` contract (you could say that a `HashSet`  fails to obey the `Set` contract if the `hashCode` is inconsistent with `equals`)…

Answer (score 1):

you might want to compare the strings using the compareTo method instead of using the equals method. That will allow the tree set to build an actual tree like structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider you `Comparator` implementation. From `java.util.Comparator#compare` javadoc:

> @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the
>        *         first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the
>        *         second.

You never return negative number in your code, consider `return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString())` as your `Comparator` implementation

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet does not seem to use equals and hashCode on the element class as HashSet uses for its duplicate removal. Instead, it uses the sorted list to eliminate duplicates. To get the desired effect (of duplicate removal), one should ensure flawless implementation of the Comparator's compare. In this case, replacing `if (o1.toString().equals(o2.toString())) { return 0; } else { return 1; }` with  `o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString())` should fix issue.